# Issue with restoring TFS Database

Tags: database, tfs

I am trying to restore TFS Database on other server. When I try to restore the database it is throwing an error

> You may need to purge the version control file cache on all TFS AT's and all TFS proxy servers that service the TFS instance prior to putting the TPC back online

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: That looks more like a warning than an error. You'll need to provide a lot more details if you want help, such as *why* you're restoring the databases. Is it for disaster recovery? An upgrade test?

Comment: I was just trying to restore the database, to verify whether the backup what I have taken is working. Just a precaution, in case if our TFS Server goes down, I should be able to restore it quickly.